# How to wipe md raid meta?

Tags: ubuntu, kvm, software-raid, md

I have Ubuntu 16.04 host with 3 Ubuntu 17.10 guests in KVM (Virtual Machine Manager 1.3.2).

I export several block devices from 2 guests to the other guest (let's call it *frontend*) via iSCSI portal created by `targetcli` util. Having imported them, I heavily use `multipath` to find same "physical" disks and `md` to create RAID 10 (say, `mdadm --create --quiet --metadata=1.2 /dev/md1 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/dm-10 /dev/dm-1`). Then I need to wipe this information out.

Here comes the problem: it does not wipe. I go through usual steps (say, to clean `md1`):

1) `mdadm -S /dev/md1`

2) `mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/md1`

3) `mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/mapper/md1`

Everything seems fine until I remove imported disks and re-import them some time later: they stochastically appear grouped in RAID. Sometimes RAID group names are far from originally created (e.g. md126 and md127, while I only created md1, md2, ... md12). These zombie RAIDs can be buried with `mdadm -S`, but they appear again the next time block devices are imported.

Why does `--zero-superblock` fail to do its work?

UPD: As @roaima mentioned, commands 2 and 3 and alike really return errors:

`Couldn't open /dev/md1 for write - not zeroing`

`Couldn't open /dev/mapper for write - not zeroing`

`Couldn't open /dev/mapper/ for write - not zeroing`

That is pretty much the same answer as if there are no such devices - any rubbish as argument will return the same error.

UPD2: I used `# cat /proc/mdstat`, which told me more about raids:

```
md124 : inactive vdg[0](S)
      5238784 blocks super 1.2

md127 : inactive vdb[1](S)
      5238784 blocks super 1.2
```

However, I still can not wipe neither `/dev/vdg` (`Couldn't open /dev/vdg for write - not zeroing`) nor `/dev/md124` (`Unrecognised md component device - /dev/md124`).

Comment: [Some other problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64977/265994) (namely, mdadm.conf problem) seems to be able to create md-126 and other big md numbers. However, it all comes from rusty meta information left from md.

Comment: Your step 2 should have reported an error about there being no metadata. Did it? If so, please add it to your question - error messages are _really really important_.

Comment: @roaima, added error on metadata deletion. I should've added it earlier, but my script didn't print all the output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It fails, because the following command:

```
mdadm --zero-superblock device
```

Takes the `device` argument as the disk(s), not the array.

So, for example this is valid and working for `sda` drive:

```
mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sda
```

or

```
mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sda1
```

depending on how you have set up the RAID.

As usual, don't forget to update your `initramfs`:

```
update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: Well, changing `/dev/mdX` with `/dev/vdX` didn't work too well  <br/>
`# mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/vdb`  <br/>
`mdadm: Couldn't open /dev/vdb for write - not zeroing`  <br/>
It reacts as if there is no device `/dev/vdb` for mdadm - any rubbish will return the same error. However, this device is real and is seen by `lsblk` and alike.

Comment: try `/dev/vdX1`

Comment: however, I believe you should first look what member in the array are with `cat /proc/mdstat`

Comment: What a handy command you gave me:  `# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md124 : inactive vdg[0](S)
      5238784 blocks super 1.2
       
md127 : inactive vdb[1](S)
      5238784 blocks super 1.2
       
unused devices: <none>
` However, I still can not wipe `/dev/vdb`. Furthermore, `mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/md127` returns new error: `# mdadm: Unrecognised md component device - /dev/md127`

Comment: I still don't get how to make newlines in comments, so I will mirror answer in the question bode.

Comment: I will be for a short time in hospital since today, so I hope I helped a little. Cheers.

Comment: /dev/vdX1 alternative didn't help. But thank you a lot for your effort, `update-initramfs -u` and `cat /proc/mdstat` did a great job.

Comment: Don't forget to stop first the array before zeroing the disk. `mdadm --stop /dev/md127`